# React fetch to Java backend returning null

Tags: java, reactjs

I currently have a react button that should be sending data from the state to a servlet via post. The server is getting hit from the fetch method but the data appears to be null.

```
 fetch(
  "http://localhost:8080/askQuestion",
  {
    method: "post",
    body: {
      question: this.state.value
    },
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/text"
    }
  }
).then(console.log(this.state.value));
```

The value in my request object for both body and question are null

```
request.getParameter("question");
request.getParameter("body");
```

Comment: Are you getting the data out of the response?  `fetch(...).then(res => res.text()).then(text => console.log(text));`?  You could also use [`.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json).

Comment: I'm sending data from React to Java

Comment: Request parameters are sort of the opposite of the body. You'd want `getInputStream`, but what you *really* should do is use a system like Spring MVC or Dropwizard that handles all of the servlet interaction for you and lets you spend your energy on business logic.

Comment: on Java Servlet side request parameters come from URL not from POST body. e.g. `http://localhost:8080/askQuestion?question=whoAmI` then there will be `request.getParameter("question")` as `"whoAmI"`. On Servlet level, as @chrylis said you have to use `getInputStream` to get a body and parse it on your own, or use one of frameworks to do not work on Servlet level. There are many available, specifically if body is in JSON format...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getInputStream()` or `getReader()` to read body attributes of the requests.

Here is an easy (not conventional) way to get your work done:

Write your body attributes in headers:

```
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/text",
      'question': this.state.value
    }
```

In backend, use `request.getHeader("question")` to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try sending json data as the `body` of your `post` request

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/askQuestion', {
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ question: this.state.value })
}).then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => console.log(res));
```